# Can not write to a list that contains map

Tags: flutter

I want to mix a list that contains maps like this:

```
initTask() async {

   List tasks = await ourDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM level1");
   Random random = Random();
   tasks.shuffle(random);

}
```

and then I got this error:

```
E/flutter (15953): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (15953): Unsupported operation: read-only
```

can anyone help?

Comment: does it happen if you create a new list too? (`List.of` / `List.from`)

Comment: no! thank you so much for your help! :-)

Comment: naturlich, your welcome

Answer (score 2):

Even if you've solved your issue there is no accepted answers so I'm gonna try explaining the solution that was provided in the comment by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink).

Usually data returned by a DB are immutable so by doing `List tasks = await ourDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM level1");` you are getting an unmodifiable list reference. To be able to modify it you need to create a new list object from your original list.

You can either use `List.of` or `List.from` to generate a new modifiable list object containing all the items from your query.

```dart
List tasks = List.from(await ourDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM level1"));
List tasks = List.of(await ourDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM level1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this, (to generate a new modifiable list),

```
List tasks = [...await ourDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM level1")];
```